# Outlook - Automatically create folders when importing rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have a set of rules for Outlook (desktop) I'd like to share with my co-workers. Only problem is every time I import the rules all of the "destinations" are folders that don't yet exist on their machine. Instead of just creating the folders along with importing the rules, it just breaks all the rules until I manually create the folders and adjust each rule.

- Is there some sort of way I can have it create the folders upon import

Or

- Can I export a list of my folders somehow and then create them based on that list on their machine? … As I type this I'm realizing I may have to delve into VBA for Outlook, but I will post this in hopes there is a simpler solution.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using the "Archive Feature" and making an "Archive" with just your folder structure and no e-mails. You can them open this Archive on the client, copy the folder structure and close the archive. Viola, you have created the folders desired.

This is definitely possible via VBA as well, I may look into it, but for now this method is the best/easiest I have found.

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Export+and+Import+Folder+Structure+Outlook

https://www.msoutlook.info/question/copy-mailbox-folder-structure-to-new-pst

Answer (score 1):

No option to automatically create folders based on rules. You can just run VBA code on user's side to automatically create folders for them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365384/check-if-an-outlook-folder-exists-if-not-create-it

Comment: I found using the 'Archive' Feature was better, I may look into importing the archive via VBA